# ASIHTTPRequest set timeout

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

How can I set the session timeout using ASIHTTPRequest ?

Thanks

Comment: Just as an FYI, the author of ASIHTTPRequest has officially stopped supporting it, and hasn't even used it himself in awhile. You can read all about it at his [blog](http://allseeing-i.com/). Another great async HTTP library is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking), written by the Gowalla dev team.

Answer (score 40):

You can set the default timeout for ASIHttpRequest by using:

```
    [ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:20];
```

Is that what your looking for?

Answer (score 18):

Given an instance of ASIHttpRequest, you can use

```
asiRequest.timeOutSeconds = 20;
```

This is useful if you only want to change the timeout from the default for one request.